# How to change scale of y-axis on timelion charts

Tags: kibana, kibana-5, timelion

Can I change y-axis scale on timelion charts? If so, how can I accomplish that?

I'm interested in only changing scale of my y-axis, I don't want to modify values of my series.

In any other visualisations I have that "Y-Axis Scale" option which I can set to "square root" receiving desired effect. But no matter what I'm unable to do the same for timelion charts. The effect you can see on the image below.

[image: desired effect]

I'm using Kibana 5.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Kibana 5.4 release will have logarithmic timelion y-axis
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logarithmic-scale-for-kibana-timeli-y-axis/81942

Comment: As a matter of factly, after much trial and error I came to conclusion that this is not possible yet and was just waiting for someone to confirm that. Thanks.